# Find any possible bondings of a list and predicate

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, predicate

My task is that I want to create a function that finds any possible "bondings" of a given list and a predicate but I can't find the right solution.

a bonding for `ls` for binary predicate `p` is a list of pairs `bs :: [ (a,a) ]` such that the following conditions hold

1. Every element in `ls` appears exactly once in `map fst bs` and exactly once in `map snd bs`
2. If a pair `(x,y)` appears in `bs` then both `x` and `y` must appear in `ls`.
3. If a pair `(x,y)` appears in `bs` then `(y,x)` also appears in `bs`.
4. If a pair `(x,y)` appears in `bs` then `x` does not equal `y`.
5. If a pair `(x,y)` appears in `bs` then `p x y` is `True`.

Furthermore, the function that I thought it will be useful for this problem is the following `findBonding :: Eq a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [(a,a)]` such that `findBonding p ls` takes `p` as predicate and `ls` as a list of integers.

For example, `findBonding (\x -> \y -> odd(x+y)) [2,3,4,5,6,7]` should return `Just [(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4),(6,7),(7,6)]`

Is it a good idea to declare `findBonding` with `foldr` of the `ls` (the list) and then `p` (the predicate) to be the function that should declare which pairs to find and then to loop over every two items to find the correct pairs and to return them as a list of lists.

Comment: Why shouldn't `(2,5)` or `(3,4)` be in the returned list in your example?

Comment: And what's the difference between returning `Just []` and returning `Nothing`? If they should mean the same thing, or if one is impossible, then your function's return value shouldn't be wrapped in a `Maybe`.

Comment: It totally can be one of the pairs yes! The idea is that it returns one possible list of pairs.

Comment: So for example if we pass `findBonding (\x -> \y -> even(x+y)) [2,3,4,5,6,7]` then the  function returns `Nothing` as no bonding exists in this case because no matter how the first two pairs are created you will always end up adding an odd and even value together for the third pair

Comment: Wait, I think I see the issue now: by "bonding", you mean the first element of each tuple in the output list should be the same as the input list, right?

Comment: Exactly yes! Every element of the list should be the first one of the pair list. For example [2,3,4,5,6,7] is the input list then the output list of lists should be [(2,_),(3,_),(4,_,...]

Comment: Why isn't `[(2,2),(3,3),(4,2),(5,3),(6,2),(7,3)]` valid for your `even` example?

Comment: Because no matter how the first two pairs are created you will always end up adding an odd and even value together for the third pair.

Comment: Oh, so you can't reuse elements on the right hand side of the tuples? In that case, is this definition correct? "A bonding with predicate `p :: a -> a -> Bool` of `xs :: [a]` is `ys :: [(a,a)]` such that `map fst ys == xs`, ``map snd ys `elem` permutations xs``, and `all (uncurry p) ys` all hold?

Comment: Also I though about is we say that a bonding for ls for binary predicate p is a list of pairs bs :: [ (a,a) ] such that the following conditions hold 1. Every element in ls appears exactly once in map fst bs and exactly once in map snd bs 2. If a pair (x,y) appears in bs then both x and y must appear in ls. 3.If a pair (x,y) appears in bs then (y,x) also appears in bs. 4. If a pair (x,y) appears in bs then x does not equal y. 5. If a pair (x,y) appears in bs then p x y is True

Comment: Okay, that seems mostly equivalent to my definition, but one quibble: why do you need point 3 of your definition?

Comment: Yes I think is correct since there are no duplicate elements in the list and if multiple possible bondings appear or no possible bonding the returns Nothing that is why we set to Maybe and return Nothing in case of no results

Comment: I guess just to clarify. Those are things that I have written down to help me and wanted to share :D

Comment: Okay, now I think I see. Give me a few minutes to edit my answer to satisfy all of those constraints.

Comment: There was no attempt made, so I voted to close. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Answer updated. See if that does what you want now.

Answer (score 4):

With your final definition of a "bonding", this should do what you want:

```
import Data.Maybe

-- > removeEach [1,2,3,4] == [(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,3,4]),(3,[1,2,4]),(4,[1,2,3])]
removeEach :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
removeEach [] = []
removeEach (x:xs) = (x,xs):map (fmap (x:)) (removeEach xs)

-- > findBonding (\x -> \y -> odd(x+y)) [2,3,4,5,6,7] == Just [(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4),(6,7),(7,6)]
-- > findBonding (\x -> \y -> even(x+y)) [2,3,4,5,6,7] == Nothing
findBonding :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [(a,a)]
findBonding f = listToMaybe . go where
  go [] = [[]]
  go (x:xs) = [(x,y):(y,x):xys | (y,ys) <- removeEach xs, f x y && f y x, xys <- go ys]
```

I created the helper function `removeEach` to, for each element in a list, provide that element plus the list without it.

The `findBonding` function takes the head of the list `x`, then finds an element `y` in the list such that `f x y` and `f y x` both hold, yields those pairs, and then recurses on the remainder of the list. It uses the outer list as a nondeterminism monad to ensure that if any possible combination of pairings work, it will find one.

Comment: your last sentence does not describe what your code is actually doing. (I can't read the question in its current ill-formatted state so I can't see whether it does what the OP asks for or not.)

Comment: @WillNess How's the wording now?

Comment: what I meant was, on the face of it, it doesn't find "a" matching element but rather all matching elements, and it recurses not on the  tail without the element but rather whole list without the element. you've left that part out now, so what is meant by "remainder" is now a bit unclear.

Comment: @WillNess "it recurses not on the tail without the element but rather whole list without the element" But I pattern-match the argument as `(x:xs)`, so `xs` is already the tail, and then each result of `removeEach xs` gives me a `ys` which is that without the matching element, and is what I recurse on.

Comment: I missed the `listToMaybe` when I first commented, and was only referring to the list comprehension part. with `listToMaybe` what you wrote is perfectly correct.